# Is it possible to disable `optimistic rendering` caching behaviour in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

As per
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Caching.html#optimistic-rendering

When navigating from a list to a single item the same record is reused, problem is that if computed fields are added only to the getOne dataProvider response (they would be too expensive for the list) these fields are empty.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly why this is a problem to you because the missing fields will be loaded eventually after the `getOne` completes.

But if you really want to disable the cache in queries, you need to [provide your own QueryClient](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#queryclient) and set it to disable the cache (probably by setting the `cacheTime` option to `0`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: RE: the missing fields will be loaded eventually after the getOne completes -

When clicking on "edit" or "show" from a list the `getOne` is not called, I am checking now the network tab and there is only the initial `getList` call. Setting `cacheTime` to 0 does the job though!